# How to select text with mouse cursor in iTerm 2?

Tags: iterm

I want to select text in iTerm just like I can in Powershell: with mouse cursor. By holding LMB and selecting it and then

- pressing backspace to delete everything I selected
- entering any character or pasting to replace selected
- copying it with command+c

I tried shift+left arrow and shift+right arrow combinations but no luck

[image]

This is my preferences (where "natural selection" must be):

[image]